# Dynamic delete on jsp file

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts2

i want to remove some table lines dynamicaly using struts2 and ajax.

i got an object "object1" which contains a list of "object2"

```
public class Object1 {
[...]
private int id;
[...]
private List<Object2> objs2;
[...]
}
```

in a jsp file a display informations about object1 in a form to be able to modify some input. 
To display the list i use an iterator.

```
<s:iterator value="object1.objs2" status="objsStatus">
```

this work fine, and i want to be able to delete one of these object2. so i put a link after each object2 which call a "delete" action with struts2-jquery.

```
<s:url id="delObject" value="/deleteObject2.action"/>
<sj:a id="delObj%{#objsStatus.index}" href="%{delObj}?object2.name=%{name}" targets="result">delete</sj:a>
```

my struts.xml

```
<action name="deleteObject2" class="Object2Action" method="deleteObj">
   <result></result>
</action>
```

this also works fine BUT (there always a but...) i have to "refresh" manually the page to see the "new" list of object2. is it possible to call a javascript function on result success to remove the appropriate table line, using for example:

```
 $(this).closest('tr:not(:only-child)').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try Reversen AJAX in jQuery. It will push data when it changed on server.

http://blog.jamieisaacs.com/archives/404

http://plugins.jquery.com/plugin-tags/reverse-ajax